# Javascript Variables in MVC Partial Views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, partial-views

This might be quite simple but I am having difficulties with it.  I have a view where I am setting a javascript variable, within that view I display a partial view using `RenderPartial` like so:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView");}
```

I need access to a js variable set in my View, in my PartialView.  Is this possible? I know there are several other ways to pass data using models but for my unique scenario it would be very helpful if I could do it this way as I am already passing a model so I can't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you pass your model into your partial view ? 
anyway you can add your property to window object and use it in your partial view.

UPDATE: 
What I meant was to open script tag in your view as follows :

```
<script>
        window.test = "test value";
</script>
```

and use it in your partial view as follows :

```
<script>
       alert( window.test);
</script>
```

BTW you can pass additional info to you partial view . Html.Partial accepts a third parameter which is viewData dictionary .

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", yourModel, new ViewDataDictionary(){ {"AdditionalModel", value} })
```

and you can access it in your partial view by its name :

```
ViewData["AdditionalModel"]
```

sorry for the late response

Comment: As mentioned I am already passing a model and this particular value is not in the model.  Can you post sample code?

Comment: I tried creating a global variable in my view like so 'window.locid=6' and then using window.locid in my partial view but it is undefined.  What am I doing incorrectly?